# Typescript not ignoring node_modules

Tags: typescript

My directory structure:

- frontend

  -- node_modules
- backend

  -- node_modules
- tsconfig.json

In my tsconfig.json, I have:

```
"exclude": [
    "frontend/node_modules", "backend/node_modules"
  ]
```

Still, I get errors from packages in node_modules.

What am I doing wrong?

// Per

Comment: Can you show the error?

Comment: It's just typescript errors from the external packages. Errors that should be ignored.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Why `"exclude"` doesn't work:

> `"exclude"` only prevents items from being included by `"include"`; it doesn't prevent them from being included via `import` statements or `<reference>`s. If you import [the module] `levelup`, and `levelup` imports `leveldown`, then excluding `leveldown` or `node_modules` won't have an effect. ([reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/747xz7/suppress_errors_in_node_modules/#CommentTopMeta--Created--t1_dnx7af1))

TS reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude

Maybe you should try [the option `--skipLibCheck`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

See also the FAQ: *[Why is a file in the exclude list still picked up by the compiler?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-a-file-in-the-exclude-list-still-picked-up-by-the-compiler)*

Comment: So there is no option to exclude directories?

Comment: @Joe Not if your code imports something from these directories.